# SQLAlchemy pagination with a filter query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to paginate the results I get from a query in a Flask app.

Currently my query that works fine looks like this:

```
data = Students.query.filter_by(campus=campus.title()).order_by(Students.level.desc()).all()
```

But when I try to paginate it using `.paginate()` method it says Pagination object is not iterable.

Example:

```
POST_PER_PAGE = 30
page = 1

data = Students.query.filter_by(campus=campus.title()).order_by(Students.level.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=POST_PER_PAGE)
```

Anyway solution to this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Pagination` object has an `items` property that holds the items on the page.

Add `.items` after `.paginate(...)`

Comment: Good god. I really should start reading the documentation properly. Thanks a lot!